# When to use static initial block in JAVA?

Tags: java

Can anyone please explain me in which scenario we use static initial block?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use it as a "constructor" for static data in your class. For example, a common situation might be setting up a list of special words:

```
private static final Set<String> special = new HashSet<String>();
static {
    special.add("Java");
    special.add("C++");
    ...
}
```

These can then be used later to check if a string matches something interesting.

Answer (score 3):

The most common scenario is loading some resources on class load, for example loading library for JNI

Answer (score 0):

And another common one is when some of the code you need to use to create your statics throw exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Another example is java.lang.Object

```
public class Object {

    private static native void registerNatives();
    static {
        registerNatives();
    }
...
```

Answer (score -3):

I use them all the time to initialize lists and maps.

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(){{
    add("blah");
    add("blah2");
}};
for(String s : myList){
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: He was asking about static initializers. That's an example of an instance (non-static) initializer.

Comment: (It is a good example of an instance initializer though, which is useful for setup in anonymous inner classes as you demonstrated)

Comment: Just be aware that that actually creates a subclass of ArrayList!

Comment: I know.  It's not the most memory efficient thing either from what I've heard.

Comment: This is definitely frowned upon, creating the subclass of ArrayList. Generally, the more preferred approach for this would be:

    List<String> myList = Arrays.asList("blah", "blah2");

Only problem here is that you can't control the type of the List, if that is important to you.